# .val on input adjusting HTML but not changing value in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to validate the range input type using JavaScript with jQuery's val method. It outputs to HTML fine but will not log the changes to value in the console(as the slider is moved the console's log stays at 5)

http://jsfiddle.net/mx6QY/1/

HTML

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" value="5" id="slider" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
  $(function(){  
    var val = $('#slider').val();  
        output  = $('#output');  

    output.html(val);  

    $('#slider').change(function(){  
        output.html(this.value); 
    });

    console.log(val);
    if(val === 1) {
      console.log('test');
    }

});
```

Comment: variable `val = $('#slider').val();` is initialize first time. and then you call the stored `val` variable value.`val` value not changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the logger into the event handler function :

```
$('#slider').change(function(){
    var val = this.value;
    output.html(val); 
    console.log(val);
    if(val === 1) {
          console.log('test');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `console.log()` inside the `change` event handler.

```
  $(function(){  
    var val = $('#slider').val();  
        output  = $('#output');  
        output.html(val);  

    $('#slider').change(function(){  
        output.html(this.value);
        console.log(this.value);
        if(this.value == 1) {
          console.log('test');
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mx6QY/4/